# Block until boost::signal is called

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

Is there an easy way to wait for a boost::signal to be called? I have a signal that is called on every draw cycle in a GUI and I want a different thread to call a function and then wait for the next draw cycle (when the signal is called again so that I know the result of the function has been applied).

I think one solution would be to setup a connection with that signal to another function that will throw a custom event and have the original function block until it gets that event. However, that doesn't seem like the most elegant solution. Is there a better way?

Comment: Did I understand your question correctly? I wasn't completely sure which thread you wanted to block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to use signals for this?

Thread A: Drawing thread
Thread B: Other thread doing some work in response

Thread B could block on a condition. Thread A sets this condition true, which allows thread B to do some work. Thread B sets the condition to false and blocks on this condition.

If you really need to use the boost::signal you could connect it to a function that sets this condition true.